# Passing URL as a parameter to Jetpack Compose Navigation

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have created a destination for `HistoryDetail` screen in my app.

```
composable(
    route = "HistoryDetail/{webpage}",
    arguments = listOf(
        navArgument("webpage") {
            type = NavType.StringType
        }
    ),
) { entry ->
    val text = entry.arguments?.getString("webpage") ?: ""
}
```

When I try to navigate to that screen by calling:

```
navController.navigate("HistoryDetail/http://alphaone.me/")
```

I'm getting `illegalArgumentException` with the below message.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation destination that matches request NavDeepLinkRequest{ uri=android-app://androidx.navigation/HistoryDetail/http://alphaone.me/ } cannot be found in the navigation graph NavGraph(0x0) startDestination={Destination(0x78c9ba0c) route=Home}
```

Edit:

It works if I call: `navController.navigate("HistoryDetail/test")`.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Navigation routes are equivalent to urls. Generally you're supposed to pass something like `id` there.

When you need to pass a url inside another url, you need to encode it:

```
val encodedUrl = URLEncoder.encode("http://alphaone.me/", StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString())
navController.navigate("HistoryDetail/$encodedUrl")
```

Note that you don't need to decode the argument on the view side, because Navigation library is gonna do it for you.

Comment: In my case, it's throwing an exception: `java.nio.charset.IllegalCharsetNameException: java.nio.charset.CharsetICU[UTF-8] at java.nio.charset.Charset.checkCharsetName(Charset.java:201)`. To solve it, I replaced `StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()` by "UTF-8" string.

Comment: And then `URLDecoder.decode(...)`

Comment: @elliptic1 actually jetpack navigation is decoding arguments on its side, so usually you don't need to do it manually

Comment: @PhilDukhov correct, but you still need to do URLEncoder.encode() when forming the route you provide to NavHostController.navigate()

Comment: @PhilDukhov I was stuck trying to figure the reason why my app is crushing when decode and the problem got solved when I saw your comment and removed the decode. Thanks a lot but I wonder why it doesn't encode and decode as well, why just decode?

Comment: @hemaezzat Navigation route is a url by itself - they need to encode their path arguments, and then decode them. If you pass encoded url as parameter, this part of the path will be secondary-encoded. I'm not sure why they decode it for two times - because first decoding would only remove first level encoding, maybe it's a fix for some corner case.

Answer (score 5):

How is this?

```kotlin
composable(
    route = "HistoryDetail?webpage={webpage}",
    arguments = listOf(
        navArgument("webpage") {
            type = NavType.StringType
        }
    ),
) { entry ->
    val text = entry.arguments?.getString("webpage") ?: ""
}
```

Comment: it could still be an issue if it's not the last argument, or if you need >1 urls for whatever reason

Comment: can we add another params besides webpage?