# Send a string arrayList between two composable functions

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to send a string Arraylist between two compose functions. Each one of those functions are different screens.
I tried converting the Arraylist to gson string but got a deep navigation link error.

```
composable(
            route = Screen.ProductPhotos.route+"/{photos}",
        arguments = listOf(
            navArgument("photos"){
            }

        )
        ) {
            entry->
            ProductPhotos(photos = entry.arguments?.getString("photos")!!)
        }
```

this is for navigation for the composable function ProductPhotos.

```
 .clickable(onClick = {
                                            var connectionsJSONString = Gson().toJson(messagesList[index].images)
                                            connectionsJSONString=Gson().toJson(messagesList[index].images).toString()
                                           
                                            navController.navigate(Screen.ProductPhotos.withArgs(
                                            connectionsJSONString
                                            ))

                                        }),
```

this code is inside another composable function and that is where I navigate to the product photos screen

```
fun withArgs(vararg args: String): String {
    return buildString {

        append(route)
        args.forEach { arg ->
            append("/$arg")
            Log.d("baga",route)

        }
    }
}
```

This is withArgs function.
I tried using normal string it works fine it seems the problem that those strings stored in the array are firebase store URL
this is an example for the error

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation destination that matches request NavDeepLinkRequest{ uri=android-app://androidx.navigation/productPhotos/["https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/products-app-c0516.appspot.com/o/images%2Fc27f0948-d833-4ee1-84e7-1a629bd3f4de.jpg?alt\u003dmedia\u0026token\u003d1d44abe6-f106-4186-8462-ed246636c289"] } cannot be found in the navigation graph NavGraph(0x0) startDestination={Destination(0xfdb9e2f) route=Login_screen}
```

Comment: provide your code so others can help you, Thanks

Comment: Ok I added the code

Comment: See how you can [encode URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68951045/3585796) to pass through navigation, and check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69060224/3585796) from the Compose maintainer on why what you are doing is considered bad practice.